# excel 2010 vba user menu to store selection as variable

Tags: excel, vba

In the below `excel 2010 VBA` I am trying to create a user menu that stores a selection (there are only 2 choices) in the variable `strInput`. That selection will be used later on but I am not sure if I am doing that in the below. Is the 1 or 2 from the section being stored or the unique 5 digit code? Is there a better way? Thank you very much:).

**VBA**

```
Dim Msg, Title As String
Dim MyInput As Integer

' Define message."
Msg = "Which array was used ? " _
& vbNewLine & "Enter 1 for Design: 00000" & vbNewLine _
& "Enter 2 for Design: 11111"

Title = "Selection of Application" ' Define title.

While MyInput.Value <> 1 And MyInput.Value <> 2

MyInput = InputBox(Msg, Title)
Select Case MyInput
    Case 1
        MsgBox "User chose Design 1"
    Case 2
        MsgBox "User chose Design 2"
    Case Else
        MsgBox “Invalid Entry. Try again.”
End Select

Wend

'STORE SELECTION '
Dim strInput As Integer
strInput = MyInput.Value

' CONVERT USER CHOICE '
If MyInput = 1 Then
strInput = "00000"
Else
strInput = "11111"
End If
```

**desired:**

user selects 1, so `00000` would be stored in `strInput` but user selects 2, so `11111` would be stored in `strInput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user entered value is stored however this may not be 1 or 2 as there is no restriction in place to inhibit users from entering an incorrect value. Try the code below which keeps on asking the question until a valid number (1 or 2) has been entered by the user.

```
Dim Msg, Title As String
Dim MyInput As Integer

 ' Define message."
Msg = "Which array was used ? " _
& vbNewLine & "Enter 1 for Design: 00000" & vbNewLine _
& "Enter 2 for Design: 11111"

Title = "Selection of Application" ' Define title.

While MyInput.Value <> 1 And MyInput.Value <> 2

    MyInput = InputBox(Msg, Title)
    Select Case MyInput
        Case 1
            MsgBox "User chose Design 1"
        Case 2
            MsgBox "User chose Design 2"
        Case Else
            MsgBox “Invalid Entry. Try again.”
    End Select

Wend

'STORE SELECTION '
Dim strInput As Integer
strInput = MyInput.Value
```

Comment: I get `While MyInput`  Invalid qualifier.  Thank you :).

Comment: I removed the `.value` and the error is gone, however it looks like the 1 or 2 is being stored, not the `00000` or `11111`, is that beacause of the `.value`?  Thank you ).

Comment: I have edited the `vba` in my post to convert the  user choice (or so I think). Is this correct/the right way?  Thank you :).

Comment: "strInput" is declared as an Integer. Change it to String

Comment: And yes, remove .Values from all MyValues